Clarification on Using `add` and `move` Methods with CollectionProperty
I'm working on a Blender add-on and I've been trying to understand the correct usage of the add and move methods with bpy.props.CollectionProperty. While I have a general understanding of their usage from sample code and examples, I'm having trouble finding explicit documentation on these methods.
I have checked the Blender API documentation for bpy.props.CollectionProperty and bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection, but couldn't find clear information on how these methods should be used. Specifically, I'm looking for detailed descriptions similar to:
move(from_index, to_index)
PARAMETERS:
  from_index (int in [-inf, inf]) – From Index, Index to move
  to_index (int in [-inf, inf]) – To Index, Target index

My Questions

Is there a page in the documentation that clearly explains the collection.add and collection.move methods?
When specific details are not available in the documentation, is it a correct approach to learn from sample code and actual usage examples? Are there other recommended resources or best practices for understanding these methods?

Background

I've checked bpy.props.CollectionProperty and bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection, but couldn't find explicit documentation for these methods.
I'm an amateur coder, and I realize my confusion might be due to simple search errors or not knowing implicit conventions and practices.

Thanks in advance for your help!
